# Jenkins: Getting the username from a build triggered remotely

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have set up a way for my team to click on some links to trigger some jenkins jobs. For this I have used the "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" option

I need to send an email after that detailing who triggered the job, but I have noticed that triggering this way the cause gets registered as Cause.RemoteCause instead of Cause.UserIdCause. This does not have info on the user who triggered it, even though they need to log in.

I have not been able to find any other way of getting the user's name. Is it even possible with remotely triggered builds? If so, how would I do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?